# Given a primary key, is it possible to find all foreign keys in EF Core model?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I'm working with a rather large EF core model that has all tables and relationships defined in code that wind up attached to a context object.  If I have a primary key, is there a clean/efficient way to get all the dependent columns in the model?

As an example of what I'm working with, this snippet works to find a primary key's name for a given table (the table is known by its type T which is a parameter to the function in which this code lives):

```
var keyName = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof (T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(x => x.Name).Single();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer while poking through the properties of they key object.  Instead of getting the name, get the object itself, then call these two other methods to get the foreign keys that reference the primary key:

```cs
var key = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof (T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.FirstOrDefault();
var foreignkeys = key.GetContainingPrimaryKey().GetReferencingForeignKeys();
```

Comment: Great answer, this trully helped me. But if you look into the documentation, there are some methods there that makes this even easier. `GetForeignKeys` `GetKeys`, etc. Worth to have a look [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ireadonlyentitytype?view=efcore-6.0)

Comment: Needed to use var foreignkeys = key?.FindContainingPrimaryKey()?.GetReferencingForeignKeys();